Sorting arm / funnel
I want to make sorting arm thru which LEGO brick will fall and the arm will distribute it into 16 boxes bellow. The kicker is the arm would be directly above the plate with 16 boxes. So it needs ability to drop brick directly bellow itself. And it would probably needs some extending ability to send brick to box far or close. I don't anticipate the arm moving on any axis (except rotation) as it needs to be attached to fixture above. At the moment I don't know if arm will need to be in the corner or in the middle. I want to make LEGO sorting machine but I want it to be relatively compact. You can see the drawing bellow. Are there some mechanical solutions which could help with this? The arm would be actuated by servos or step motors or what ever is best fit. As you probably guessed I'm quite new to mechanical and electrical engineering and this is my hobby project to learn new things (and get my heap of LEGOs sorted in the process)


So 14 boxes as stated or 16 as drawn? Why not put the boxes on a circle and then control the rotation to choose a box?

Seems easy enough as long as one piece can be dispensed at a time. What are you using to limit and control the flow of pieces?

Based on the information you've given us, any 2 axis motion system should work fine. I recommend basing your design on a 3d printer x/y gantry since they're cheap and common, and should do what you need.

it will be 16 boxes.. Gantry is an interesting idea, thank you for suggesting it. I don't want circle because it should be compact and I want to be able to pull out of the tray with boxes and utilize as much space as possible. I wonder how fast those things can go. I would like to finish the cycle in < 1s.
This is a first part I'm working on, btw if you have suggestion how to separate pieces please don't hesitate to share it. I saw people achieve it with vibration "belt"

what about 16 funnels arranged in a circle, feeding into a 4x4 grid .... have you considered this?  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=conveyor+sorter&iax=images&ia=images

@jsotola I'm not sure I'm following. Like and static adapter between circle and rectangle and on top of that rotate bucket which drops part into appropriate funnel which drops into the 4x4 pattern?

yes, an adapter from circular to square ... if it does not have to be square,  then a sloped ramp with diverters might be the fastest
